# Solving $P(Z\le a) = 0.005$

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

How do i solve

$$\int^a_{-\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \, dz = 0.005\text{ ?}$$

I thought of using the substitution $z = 1/x$ which gets me to

$$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\frac{1}{a}}_0\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2x^2}} \, dx = 0.005$$

But i have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Uh this function is unbounded at infinity.. Do you mean to have a negative in the exponent?

Comment: @CameronWilliams : It seems nearly obvious that this is a typo and what was intended was $\exp(-z^2/2). \qquad$

Comment: If you do, this can't be easily solved by typical techniques anyway.

Comment: Perhaps OP meant the standard normal distribution

Comment: There are standard numerical techniques for this well known function. But they are numerical; there is no closed form.

Comment: @MichaelHardy from a   quick online search I found it evaluates to $\frac12\big(1+\text{erf}(\frac{x}{\sqrt2}))$

Comment: @TheIntegrator The error function $\text{erf}$ is not an elementary function: its definition is an integral very similar to the one above

Comment: @rbird i know that, just wanted to show that it could be evaluated in this way

Comment: Yeah sorry i didn't put it in, but i am refering to the standard normal distribution., let me make those changees.

Comment: @TheIntegrator My point is that writing it like this does not really tell us anything new

Comment: @Danxe The easiest way to solve this would be to use standard normal tables

Comment: @TheIntegrator : Your comment seems perfectly obvious, since it merely restates the matter in only slightly different language, but since you pinged me, I wonder if you intended it to be relevant to something I said.

Comment: @rbird yeah but i was wondering if there was a way to compute it out.

Comment: @MichaelHardy i misunderstood your comment and tagged you. I was just pointing out what it evaluates to.

Comment: Since the solution requires the inverse of the error function to solve for $a$, it is clear that there is no other solution in terms of elementary function. You can stop trying substitutions and the like.

Comment: @Danxe As others have said, it's only possible using numerical methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  This is a classic example of something that you "solve" by tables, graphically, or by numerical methods.

By table, we work from this [standard normal table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table), which is a one-sided, right-sided table, so we want to find $\frac{1}{2} - 0.005 = 0.495$ in this table and then negate it.  We see that the cumulative value of $0.495$ occurs between $Z = 2.57$ with $0.49492$ and $Z = 2.58$ with $0.49506$.  Linearly interpolating, we have $0.495$ when $Z = 2.5757$, so your value of $a$ is approximately $-2.5757$.

By graph, we can use many different methods.  For instance, from a left-tailed log-linear plot of the CDF, its height is $0.005$ when $a$ is very slightly greater than $-2.6$.
[image: a left-tailed log-linear plot of the CDF of the standard normal distribution]

Numerically, we proceed by unbounded binary search, then bisection.  We start by evaluating your integral at $a = 0$ by symmetry, giving $1/2$.  Since the value of the integral you want is in $(0,1/2)$, we proceed in the interval $a \in (-\infty, 0)$.  \begin{align*}
a && \text{test} && &\text{value} \\
(-\infty,0)  && -1 && 0.&15866 \\
(-\infty,-1) && -2 && 0.&022750 \\
(-\infty, -2) && -4 && 0.&000\,031\,671 \\
(-4,-2) && -3 && 0.&001\,350 \\
(-3,-2) && -2.5 && 0.&006\,209\,7 \\
(-3,-2.5) && -2.75 && 0.&002\,979\,8 \\
(-2.75,-2.5) && -2.625 && 0.&004\,332\,5 \\
(-2.625,-2.5) && -2.5625 && 0.&005\,196\,1 \\
(-2.625,-2.5625) && -2.59375 && 0.&004\,746\,8 \\
\end{align*}
Stopping here, because we've adequately demonstrated the method.  We can do two things.  First, we know that the desired value of $a$ is between $-2.59375$ and $-2.5625$ and we could halve the size of this interval as many times as needed to meet an accuracy goal by further rounds of bisection.  Alternatively, we could linearly interpolate over the tiny interval left to get a "sharper" final number: $a$ is approximately $-2.5761$.

Now, in the late $20^\text{th}$ and early $21^\text{st}$ centuries, we can use computer algebra systems to compute your $a$ to arbitrary precision.  Much theoretical and numerical technology has been brought to these systems.  Mathematica 11.2 finds that your integral is $\frac{1}{2} \left(1 + \mathrm{erf}(a/\sqrt{2})\right)$, and that this inverts to $a = \sqrt{2} \,\mathrm{erf}^{-1}(2z-1)$ (where $z$ is the $Z$ score), and then evaluating this with $z = 5/1000$ to $20$ decimal places, we get $a = -2.575\,829\,303\,548\,900\,760\,97\dots$ where the elided digits would round the last digit shown up to $8$.  You may imagine this number was found by further bisection, but this has been augmented with machinery to control loss of precision/accuracy and other defects of numerical calculations.  (For instance, many specific transcendental functions, like $\mathrm{erf}$ and its inverse have [efficient evaluation techniques](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540112000697), which we have ignored.)  Research in this machinery is still ongoing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form analytical solution, hence you should use the standard normal  distribution tables, i.e., 
$$
\mathbb{P}( Z\le a)=0.005 \to a=\Phi^{-1}(0.005)\approx-2.58
$$